# Matlab Operators

Tags: matlab

I am studying for cumulative exam I have tomorrow and I got the following question wrong on a previous exam. I was hoping someone could explain this question to me? What does (~m) mean?

The question says:
After executing the following script, what is the value of m?

```
a=1; b=2; m=0;  
if (~m)  
    m = m+1;  
    if (a-b > 0)  
        m = m+1;  
    else  
        m = m -1;  
    end  
elseif (m > 1)  
    m = m + 2;  
else  
    m = m - 2;  
end
```

The correct answer is 0, but why? I would have guessed that m = -2

Comment: To find out what `~` means, just type `doc ~`.

Comment: I know what ~ means, but I wasn't sure what the logic behind writing "if NOT m"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `~` means `NOT`.  However, numeric values are all considered `TRUE` unless they are identically equal to `0`.

So, the commands which are actually executed by this logic are:

```
m = m+1;  %Following if (~m)
m = m-1;  $Following else
```

Also, there is a nested `if` statement in the code.  It will be easier to read if you used multiple level indentations.

Comment: Thank you! I knew that '~' means "not", but I wasn't sure what "if (~m)" actually referred to